# Electrodynamics boundary conditions with complex $\epsilon$ and $\mu$

Tags: electromagnetism, boundary-conditions

I wonder if the usual derivation for boundary conditions at an interface given in EMT textbooks hold for complex permittivity and/or permeability? Do the fields carry phase information themselves(i.e. are they complex quantities?) Furthermore, how can I take the limits for infinite permeability and/or permeability in the most general case? I just got confused on this matter and would like some clear explanation if possible.

Comment: Do you mean how do we interpret that the normal component of E should change by a factor $\epsilon$ etc. ?

Comment: Yeah that kind of things.